# Cache-Control header not being sent from Cloudfront Custom Object Caching

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

All my assets are stored on S3.

I setup CloudFront on top of it. Therefore I only have one origin on this distribution.

Here is my configuration.
[image]

When I get an asset (in this case a css file), here are the headers that are returned.

```
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 431206
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 19:58:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Apr 2019 19:19:06 GMT
ETag: "157d6f76c8edfc3329062f511be86149"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 12
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 67c0f7cc5ebd46ca00c423ff8dac32d3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: uqlSS3nsE_s2gfeN8XRaLWsrNoLJw7ap7Kuaqv92GbUVcXFKJD4dog==
```

My expectation is that `Cache-Control` header would be set, but clearly isn't being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is incorrect.

These settings do not set or modify `Cache-Control` headers -- they only adjust the values CloudFront adopts for its internal TTL for each object.

To set `Cache-Control` on objects, the header needs to be sent when the object is uploaded to S3, or it can be added in CloudFront using a Lambda@Edge trigger.

See [No Cache-Control Header for files from AWS CloudFront with S3 Origin](https://serverfault.com/q/770302/153161) on Server Fault.

See also [What is Cloudfront Minimum TTL for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51074418/1695906) and [Confused with minimum, maximum and default TTL in CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343759/1695906) here on Stack Overflow.